# JavaScript: reading an excel-cell value

Tags: javascript, excel, testing, automated-tests

I am working on a task of automation testing and I need to access an excel file to get the input data.

I need help on how to access specific cell values from a local excel file using Javascript.

I have an excel file in my local storage, which has the word 'After Life' in its cell 'B2'. [image]

Currently, I have made two functions: one for navigation to the desired page and the other for search. But, as I don't know how to import data from a local excel file, I typed the string argument 'After Life' manually for the search function.

[image]

Comment: By default, excel files are binary. CSV on the other hand, is in a text-based format. Would using CSV still fit your needs or do you need special excel functionality?

Comment: I think you need to use this exceljs package [ https://www.npmjs.com/package/exceljs ] for that kind of requirements.

Comment: Also, your question is pretty broad. Could you narrow it down by updating your question and posting code of what you already tried? How do you consume the excel file? Is it an upload in the browser or are you using node.js? At what part are you stumped?

Comment: @TomM i've updated the question now, please have a look at it

Comment: So what you need is a way to import the excel file in your unit test AND a way to access the value at B2?

Comment: @Sarmad is that correct?

Comment: @TomM importing the whole excel file is not necessarily required. The only requirement is that my code should be able to get input data from specific cells instead of me typing the input data manually

Comment: @Sarmad alright. And regarding my first question - can it be csv or does it need to be xlsx?

Comment: @TomM sorry i missed that, yeah csv is fine too

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd recommend importing the file as .csv and creating a ReadStream in conjunction with [`csv-parser`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/csv-parser) to consume and parse it in your E2E-Test.

```
const csv = require('csv-parser')
const fs = require('fs')
const results = [];

const findByKey = (key) => {
    return new Promise ((resolve, reject) => {
    
        fs.createReadStream('data.csv')
           .pipe(csv())
           .on('data', (data) => results.push(data))
           .on('end', () => {
                const searchString = results.forEach((item) => {
                    return item[key];
                });
                if (item.key && item.key.length > 0) {
                    resolve(item.key);
                } else {
                    reject();
                }
        });
    }) 
}
```

This way, you can then find the String in your Search function, if you use [`async/await`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/await).

```
 export async function search (searchText) {
     const searchString = await findByKey(searchText);
     cy.get('.gLFyf').type(searchText + '{enter}');
 }
```

and then use it like this:

```
it('should search After Life', () => {
    search('Search String 2');
});
```